# How to query a numerical column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets suppose I create a dataframe with columns and query i.e

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns=['a','b']).query('a>1')
```

This will give me

```
   a  b
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

But when dataframe values are too large and I don't have column names, how can I query a column by its index?

I tried querying by passing a number, but it's not the way of doing it.

```
pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).query('0>1') # This is what I tried.
```

How to denote `0` is the column name in query?

Expected Output:

```
   0  1
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Comment: `df.query("index > 1")`? Or are you referring to the columns? Sorry, what's your expected output?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no. I want to select the data from dataframe where column 1 has values > 1.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense to me. `query` is a lot like using the dot notation for dataframe columns. You could do `df.A`, but not `df.1`. Similarly, you can use query for such valid column names, but I don't think numbers fly.

Comment: Oh `query` can only be used only for column names which can be expressed in dot notation? Anyway I can do the operation on the fly without storing the dataframe in a variable?

Comment: This is my belief. Also, I don't think doing something like `a = 1; df.query("@a > 1")` works, because eval will resolve a to `1 > 1` which still wouldn't work.

Comment: For the index there is a way to represent the levels like `ilevel_0`, wish there was a similar name for repesenting columns.

Comment: @ayhan IIRC they added support for `level_*` (multi-index queries) in 0.22!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - No, it is supported at least in `0.13.version+` - check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) - `df.query('ilevel_0 == "red"')`

Comment: I think somebody will update the query code, let the question be open. Lets put the answer once the issue is resolved. Thankyou @ayhan for bringing it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the query is under development one possible solution is creating a monkey patch for `pd.DataFrame` to evaluate self i.e :

```
def query_cols(self,expr):
    if 'self' in expr:
        return self[eval(expr)]
    else:
        return self.query(expr)

pd.DataFrame.query_cols = query_cols

pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).query_cols('self[1] > 3')

   0  1
1  3  4
2  5  6

pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).query_cols('self[1] == 4')

   0  1
1  3  4

pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],columns=['a','b']).query_cols('a > 3')

   a  b
2  5  6
```

This is a simple trick and doesn't suit all the cases, answer will be updated when the issue with query is resolved.

Comment: Interesting approach ;)

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

An option without any monkey patching is to use `@` to define a variable and do this as follows.

```py
# If you are fond of one-liners
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]); df.query('@df[0] > 1')

# Otherwise this is the same as
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
df.query('@df[0] > 1') # @df refers to the variable df
```

Output:

```sh
   0  1
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

### References

You can find more ways of dealing with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68310692/8474894).

- [Docs: `pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

Comment: @jezrael See this method using `@` to use query on pandas dataframes with numeric column names.

Comment: @Bharath See this method using `@` to use query on pandas dataframes with numeric column names.

Comment: If I can store the data frame in the variable why would I even want to use query? I would simply do `df[df[0]>1]`. The question was about using `query` during the initialization.

Comment: @Bharath I see. But since `@` option was not mentioned, I thought of adding that here. Perhaps it will be relevant to someone else, who's probably looking for `pandas + query + numeric column name` as the search query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intermediate column with assign + a lambda function:

`pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]).assign(col=lambda x: x[0]).query("col>1")`